# How can I create my own irb using binding?

Tags: ruby, binding, irb

Trying to write a program communicating interactively to user through the command line.
We can give blocks to get evaluated or leave blank as we interact with normal irb. Something like :

```
irb(main):001:0> 1+2
#=> 3
irb(main):002:0> class Foo
irb(main):003:1>  def foo
irb(main):004:2>    print 1
irb(main):005:2>  end
irb(main):006:1> q
[2156][giles@nikola:~]$
#=> nil
```

After typing 'q' on this interactive shell we should be able to exit irb shell as well as the complete program.

I have created a program which opens this interactive session and we can perform certain operations on existing content of program. Like we can change the value of @var
irb(main):001:0> @var = 'new'
=> new

But I want to use binding to achieve this and also do not want to call irb methods using "#require 'irb' " within my code.

My solution:

```
require 'irb'
class C
    def my_method
        @var = 'hi'
        $my_binding = binding
        IRB.start(__FILE__)
    end
end

C.new.my_method
```

Expected Result: I want to implement it in a way like -

```
class Bind
  def get_binding(param)
    binding
  end
end

....
```

Comment: Look into https://github.com/pry/pry for an idea of how others do similar work.

Comment: Thanks @anothermh for guiding me. But again I will have to use require 'pry' and trying to open interactive session through binding.pry.                                               I am trying to avoid existing libraries.

Comment: I meant you should look at pry to see how _they_ do it.

Comment: Sure I got your point.

Answer (score 0):

I think I wanted something like this(IRB is created, but still unable to evaluate statements) :

```
class Demo
  def initialize(n)
    @secret = self.class.send(:define_method,n) { instance_eval"#{n}" }
  end
  def get_binding
    binding
  end
end

user_input = ''
k2 = Demo.new(user_input)
b2 = k2.get_binding

until user_input == 'q' do
  user_input = gets.chomp
  puts eval('@secret', b2)
end
```

Comment: Statements like x=1 ; y = 1 ; then enter x + y should fetch results inside irb, till q is pressed.